# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)-\frac{x^2}4}{e^{x^2}+e^{-x^2}-2}$?

Tags: limits

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^2 \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \frac{x^2}{4}}{e^{x^{2}} + e^{-x^{2}} - 2} &\overset{L}{=} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2}x}{2xe^{x^{2}} + (-2x)e^{-x^{2}}} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2}x}{2xe^{x^{2}} -2xe^{-x^{2}}} \\
&\overset{L}{=} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{2}\cos^2 \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sin^2 \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}{(2x)(2x)e^{x^{2}} - (2x)(-2x)(e^{-x^{2}})} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{2}\cos^2 \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sin^2 \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}{4x^2 e^{x^{2}} + 4x^2 e^{-x^{2}}} \\
&\overset{L}{=} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{2}\left( -\sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2} \right) - \frac{1}{2} \left( \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2} \right)}{(4x^2)(2x)e^{x^{2}} + (4x^2)(-2x)(e^{-x^{2}})} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}}{8x^3e^{x^{2}} - 8x^3 e^{-x^{2}}} \\
\end{align*}$$

After evaluating the limit as $x \to 0$, I noticed that the problem comes up to be in an indeterminate form of $0/0$. I immediately utilized the L'Hospital Rule by differentiating both the numerator and denominator.

However, after using L'Hospital rule for 5-6 times, I noticed that the question will go through a loop of $0/0$ indeterminants.

In my second attempt,
I have tried multiplying $\exp(x^2)$ in both the numerator and denominator with hopes to balance out the $\exp(x^{-2})$. However, an indeterminant is $0/0$ still resulting.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you all!

Comment: Welcome at MSE. You should use Mathjax to typeset your equations. Mathjax is similar to LaTeX.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule is *not* the alpha and omega of limits computations!

Comment: the result is zero

Comment: I don't believe in the loop of $\frac{0}{0}$. There must be errors when you apply L'Hospital rule.

Comment: I have added a picture of my L'Hospital Rule attempt in the post. Do let me know if there are any errors spotted. Thank you so much for the response!

Comment: The denominator is false after the 3rd equal sign. That said, l'Hospital rule is not the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Ah, I noticed the error of not utilising product rule - will try to rectify it asap!

Comment: @Gribouillis What would be the fastest / a faster way to approach this question?

Comment: I know that typing the equations is sometimes very tedious, but it helps you to better understand what you are doing and why you are stuck. It also protects your post from losing its meaning, if the link to the picture expires. but still gave you a "+1" for your efforts.

Comment: @MrYouMath Thank you Sir, I am really new to MSE - in fact, I have just created my account to source for help for an assignment. Will take note of your advice for future posts, thank you!

Comment: MrYouMath's answer looks like the easiest way to start.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: If you really want to use LH (have a strong look at Bernard's comment), you need to apply it four times. Just forget it ! It would be  a nightmare.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Use the Taylor approximation for sine and the exponential function.

$$\sin(u)=u-u^3/6+O(u^5)$$
$$\exp(u)=1+u+u^2/2 + O(u^3).$$

Answer (score 2):

$$=\lim_{x\to0}e^{x^2}\cdot\dfrac{\left(\sin\dfrac x2\right)^2-\left(\dfrac x2\right)^2}{(e^{x^2}-1)^2}$$

$$=-\dfrac1{2^4}\lim_{x\to0}e^{x^2}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin\dfrac x2+\dfrac x2}{\dfrac x2}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac x2-\sin\dfrac x2}{\left(\dfrac x2\right)^3}\left(\dfrac1{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{x^2}-1}{x^2}}\right)^2$$

$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin\dfrac x2+\dfrac x2}{\dfrac x2}=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\sin\dfrac x2}{\dfrac x2}+1\right)=?+1$

$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{x^2}-1}{x^2}=1$

For $I=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac x2-\sin\dfrac x2}{\left(\dfrac x2\right)^3},$ set $x=2y$

and use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion), to find $6I=1$

Comment: I always love these 'elementary' approaches :-)

Answer (score 1):

You only have to find *equivalents* for the numerator and the denominator. We'll begin with rewriting them, and use classical *Taylor's expansions*:

*Numerator:*
 $$\sin^2\dfrac x2-\dfrac{x^2}4=\dfrac{1-\cos x}{2}-\dfrac{x^2}4=\biggl[\frac12-\Bigl(\frac12-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^4}{48}+o\bigl(x^4\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr]-\frac{x^2}4=-\frac{x^4}{48}+o\bigl(x^4\bigr)$$
so the numerator is equivalent near $\,0\;$ to $-\dfrac{x^4}{48}$.

*Denominator:*
We know $\sinh u\sim_0 u$, so 
$$\mathrm e^{x^2}+\mathrm e^{-x^2}-2=1+x^2+\frac{x^4}2+o(x^4)+1-x^2+\frac{x^4}2+o(x^4)-2=x^4+o(x^4)$$
so the denominator is equivalent to $x^4$. There results that
$$\frac{\sin^2\dfrac x2-\dfrac{x^2}4}{\mathrm e^{x^2}+\mathrm e^{-x^2}-2}\sim_0\frac{-\cfrac{x^4}{48}}{x^4}=-\frac1{48}.$$

Comment: I strogly agree with your comment. The result should be $-\frac 1 {48}$. Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: It took me a hard time to find where the error came from – t shows I'm not very good at typing directly my calculations. Thanks for pointing the error!

Comment: If I was given a dime for any of this kind of mistakes, I should be a millionaire !

Comment: Is there a way to be directly in touch ? If you wish, my e-mail address is in my profile.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I don't want mine to be public, so I'll send you a private e-mail. I finally understood my confusion: rewriting as $\cosh x^2$ and a $-2$ next to it made me think of a cosh squared, not seeing that $\mathrm e^{x^2}\ne\mathrm e^{2x}$.

Comment: Thank you both Bernard & Claude, I have understood the solution to this hairy problem. Really appreciate both of you for taking the time to clarify & rectify. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, from the second expression you will get easy a result : 
$$
\lim_{x\to0} { {\sin^2({x \over 2})} - {{x^2} \over 4} \over 
{ e^{x^2}+ e^{-{x^2}}-2} } = \lim_{y\to0} { {\sin^2({\sqrt y \over 2})} - {y \over 4} \over 
{ e^y+ e^{-y}-2} }=?
$$
I do $y=x^2$. Clearly numerator is 0 and denominator is $0$. 
I will correct here. I expand function $\sin^2{y \over 2}={y \over 4} - {{y^2} \over 48}+ ...$. So, at numerator we get ${{-{y^2}}\over 48}+ ...$. At denominator a Taylor expansion get after resting 2 : $y^2 + ...$
We do a division :
$$
\lim_{y\to0} { {\sin^2({\sqrt y \over 2})} - {y \over 4} \over 
{ e^y+ e^{-y}-2} }= \lim_{y\to0} {{{ -{y^2}\over 48}} \over {y^2}} = {-1 \over 48}
$$

Comment: Why do you say clearly denominator is $\infty$?

Comment: Hi Daniel, appreciate the response. Would just like to clarify - by letting y = $x^2$, wouldn't the denominator be 0 as well? Since as y approaches 0, denominator becomes (1+1-2) = 0.

Comment: Sorry, i mistake. Both are 0, so need to look in detail using Taylor.

Comment: No problem, I would appreciate if you'd be able to rectify the approach. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the rectification Daniel, really appreciate it!

Comment: Ok. I like to help peope, but correctly. Anyway another people already give another valid answer